# Need help modifying CSS code of animated text to fit with a form I created

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add and modify some animated CSS that I found to a 'subscription form' that I originally created.  The problem is that the animation I found does not fit within the confines of my form (i.e., it's too big).  I've tried to change the font size of the animation, but that seems to make things worse. I'm not even certain that my html is 100% correct.  At best, I am a beginner.   You'll find my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
        /*Original CSS for animated text I found*/
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    body{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
      background: #343F4F;
    }
    .wrapper{
      display: flex;
    }
    .wrapper .static-txt{
      color: #000;
      font-size: 60px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    .wrapper .dynamic-txts{
      margin-left: 15px;
      height: 90px;
      line-height: 90px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .dynamic-txts li{
      list-style: none;
      color: #FC6D6D;
      font-size: 60px;
      font-weight: 500;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      animation: slide 12s steps(4) infinite;
    }
    @keyframes slide {
      100%{
        top: -360px;
      }
    }
    .dynamic-txts li span{
      position: relative;
      margin: 5px 0;
      line-height: 90px;
    }
    .dynamic-txts li span::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: #343F4F;
      border-left: 2px solid #FC6D6D;
      animation: typing 3s steps(10) infinite;
    }
    @keyframes typing {
      40%, 60%{
        left: calc(100% + 30px);
      }
      100%{
        left: 0;
      }
    }
    
      /*Original CSS for my form*/
        form {
            border: 5px solid #000;
            padding: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            border-left-width: 10px;
            border-right-width: 10px;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: #efefef;
            height: 200px;
        } 
        
        input[type=submit] {
            display: inline;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            font-weight: 300;
            border-radius: 200px;
            transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        
        input[type=submit] {
            background-color: #ff0000;
            color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        input[type=submit]:hover,
        input[type=submit]:active {
            background-color: #ff5e5e;
        } 
        
        .directions {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        input[type=text] {
            width: 200px;
        }
        
    </style>

</head>

    <body>
        <form  action="https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" `onsubmit="window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=blogspot/BKkas', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">`
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="static-txt">Subscribe</div>
            <ul class="dynamic-txts">
              <li><span>Enter Your Email</span></li>
              <li><span>To get the most recent news</span></li>
              <li><span>delivered right to your inbox.</span></li>
              <li><span>SIGN-UP NOW!</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <p><input type="text" name="email"/></p><br/>
          <input type="hidden" value="blogspot/BKkas" name="uri"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
          
        </form>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the text fit into the box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style>
        /*Original CSS for animated text I found*/
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    body{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      min-height: 80vh;
      background: #343F4F;
    }
    .wrapper{
      display: flex;
      
    }
    .wrapper .static-txt{
      color: #000;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-left:40px;
      line-height: 90px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    .wrapper .dynamic-txts{
      margin-left: 15px;
      height: 90px;
      line-height: 90px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .dynamic-txts li{
      list-style: none;
      color: #FC6D6D;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 500;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      animation: slide 12s steps(4) infinite;
    }
    @keyframes slide {
      100%{
        top: -360px;
      }
    }
    .dynamic-txts li span{
      position: relative;
      margin: 5px 0;
      line-height: 90px;
    }
    .dynamic-txts li span::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: #343F4F;
      border-left: 2px solid #FC6D6D;
      animation: typing 3s steps(10) infinite;
    }
    @keyframes typing {
      40%, 60%{
        left: calc(100% + 30px);
      }
      100%{
        left: 0;
      }
    }
    
      /*Original CSS for my form*/
        form {
            border: 5px solid #000;
            padding: 3px;
            text-align: center;
            border-left-width: 10px;
            border-right-width: 10px;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: #efefef;
            height: 200px;
        } 
        
        input[type=submit] {
            display: inline;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            font-weight: 300;
            border-radius: 200px;
            transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        
        input[type=submit] {
            background-color: #ff0000;
            color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        input[type=submit]:hover,
        input[type=submit]:active {
            background-color: #ff5e5e;
        } 
        
        .directions {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        input[type=text] {
            width: 200px;
        }
        
    </style>

</head>

    <body>
        <form  action="https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" `onsubmit="window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=blogspot/BKkas', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="static-txt">Subscribe</div>
            <ul class="dynamic-txts">
              <li><span>Enter Your Email</span></li>
              <li><span>To get the most recent news</span></li>
              <li><span>delivered right to your inbox.</span></li>
              <li><span>SIGN-UP NOW!</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <p><input type="text" name="email"/></p><br/>
          <input type="hidden" value="blogspot/BKkas" name="uri"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
          
        </form>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the animation still does not fit.  Actually looks the same as before.  When animated you should see the contents of the list box.  As is, you can only see one word.

Comment: So want all the words in the list box to be displayed?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you wanted, but I have got the li items to display all the words at once.

Comment: Strange, when I first tried it wasn't working.  Now it seems to be working.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I edited it since you said. No problem. Can you give it a tick if it answered you question?

Comment: What exactly did you change?  I would really like the font size to be bigger; at least 15px and the font size of "Subscribe" to be 15px.  When I try to change them everything is all out of alignment.

Comment: I changed the font size in .dynamic-texts li and then added top:0px to .dynamic-txts li

Comment: How about now? looks better with the text the same size.